# how save photo in telegram python bot?

Tags: python-3.x, photo, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

i want to write a telegram bot that save photos .
this is my code , but its not working.
and i don't know what is my problem?

```
def image_handler(bot, update):
    file = bot.getFile(update.message.photo.file_id)
    print ("file_id: " + str(update.message.photo.file_id))
    file.download('image.jpg')

updater.dispatcher.add_handler(MessageHandler(Filters.photo, image_handler))
updater.start_polling()
updater.idle()
```

pleas help me to solve my problem.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`update.message.photo` is an array of photos sizes (PhotoSize objects).

Use `file = bot.getFile(update.message.photo[-1].file_id)`. This will get the  image with biggest size available.

Comment: why i should write "[-1]" ?
what is this?

Comment: @Ali [-1] is the last item of array. This is how indices work in python. I recommend getting familiar with it as it's very common feature. You actually don't have to use the last item, but last image is the biggest image according to docs (https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/wiki/Code-snippets#download-a-file)

Answer (score 5):

Here is my code

```
from telegram.ext import *
import telegram

def start_command(update, context):
    name = update.message.chat.first_name
    update.message.reply_text("Hello " + name)
    update.message.reply_text("Please share your image")

def image_handler(update, context):
    file = update.message.photo[0].file_id
    obj = context.bot.get_file(file)
    obj.download()
    
    update.message.reply_text("Image received")

def main():
    print("Started")
    TOKEN = "your-token"
    updater = Updater(TOKEN, use_context = True)
    dp = updater.dispatcher
    dp.add_handler(CommandHandler("start", start_command))

    dp.add_handler(MessageHandler(Filters.photo, image_handler))

    updater.start_polling()
    updater.idle()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: `file = update.message.photo[-1].file_id` to get the biggest image.

Answer (score 1):

Unlike the accepted answer suggests, you don't actually need the `bot` object to get the file:

```py
file = update.message.photo[-1].get_file()
```

and then download the file:

```py
path = file.download("output.jpg")
```

to use it for further processing or just have it on your device : )

Answer (score 0):

Here is a vanilla python solution:

```py
import requests
from PIL import Image

# for example, we get the last message
# update = requests.post(f'https://api.telegram.org/bot{TOKEN}/getUpdates').json()['result'][-1]

msg = update['message']

# check whether the message contains a photo
if msg.get('photo', None) == None:
  return

# get the photo id with the biggest resolution
file_id = msg['photo'][-1]['file_id']

# get URL by id
file_path = requests.get(f'https://api.telegram.org/bot{TOKEN}/getFile?file_id={file_id}').json()['result']['file_path']

# open URL with Pillow
img = Image.open(requests.get(f'https://api.telegram.org/file/bot{TOKEN}/{file_path}', stream=True).raw)

# save on the disk if needed
img.save('photo.jpg')
```

Answer (score -1):

@dp.message_handler(commands='start')
9 async def s_photo(message: types.Message):
10     """getting str type of json file"""
11photostr = await bot.get_user_profile_photos(message.from_user.id)
12     """parsing str to json"""
13     photojson = json.loads(photostr.as_json())
14     """giving file unic code to get_file method"""
15     photo = await bot.get_file(photojson['photo'][0][0]['file_id'])
16     """end  downloading object with download method"""
17     downloadphoto = await photo.download('filename'+'.jpeg')