# How to receive images from Telegram Bot

Tags: python, python-telegram-bot

Can't receive images from my telegram bot, trying something like this:

```
import telegram
from telegram.ext import Updater
from telegram.ext import MessageHandler
from telegram.ext import Filters

def photo_handler(bot, update):
    file = bot.getFile(update.message.photo.file_id)
    print ("file_id: " + str(update.message.photo.file_id))
    file.download('photo.jpg')

updater = Updater(token='my token')
dispatcher = updater.dispatcher
dispatcher.add_handler(MessageHandler(Filters.photo, photo_handler))
```

No any errors while running

Comment: I already answered this question [how save photo in telegram python bot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50388435/how-save-photo-in-telegram-python-bot). First line in photo_handler needs to be file = bot.getFile(update.message.photo[-1].file_id).

Comment: @dev4Fun , what if you are sending more than one image to telegram? How can we handle such scenario?

Answer (score 0):

I've used this to send images generated by matplotlib. You can adapt it to your needs.

```
import telegram
from telegram.bot import Bot
import yachain
import cStringIO
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Agg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

cfg = yachain.Config().load("telegram.cfg")

token = cfg["token"]
chat_id = cfg["chatID"]

bot = Bot(token=token)

y = [2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20]
x = np.arange(10)
fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.subplot(111)
ax.plot(x, y, label='$y = numbers')
plt.title('Legend inside')
ax.legend()
#plt.show()

buffer = cStringIO.StringIO()
fig.savefig(buffer, format='png')

buffer.seek(0)
bot.send_photo(chat_id=chat_id,
               photo=buffer)
```

Comment: The question about how to receive a photo, not how to send it

Comment: yes, I noticed that just after I posted. I commented on that, but that comment is gone  somehow

Comment: so can anyone help me with this issue?